# Is this question on topic - Can the T.H.A.N.O.S. theory be completed?

Tags: support, specific-question

I feel like this may not be an answerable question and more specifically, that it may not be on topic, but I am curious and can not find anything online to satiate my interest...

Here is the question as I would address it:

Given the fan theory that has made the rounds to date has held up relatively well can we now complete and authenticate the idea based on what we know from events of Infinity War?

If it is not on topic is there a way I can rephrase it to "make it so?"

[image: fan theory]

Comment: It's a sample size of five with some major post-hoc tweaking (e.g. the Eye of Agamotto gets assigned to "necklace" rather than "eye"). Anyway, hasn't it already been asked?

Comment: @Adamant - I was pretty sure someone else would have beaten me to it, but I could not find anything...

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87643/51379

Comment: Actually that accepted answer even acknowledges it could be true after first saying no and updating... but I found something; I will add this as a comment to that question: https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/avengers-infinity-war-writers-debunk-that-popular-thanos-theory_us_5add1562e4b009869bfa8d87

Comment: The *accepted* answer, sure. But the best answer, with more upvotes, doesn’t.

Comment: @Adamant That link could probably be an answer here ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only is that question on-topic, but it's already been asked.

[Is "Infinity Stones making the name of Thanos" true?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87643/51379)

If you have new info, I'd suggest you add it as an answer!